# Integral of two variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the below integral
$$
\iint \phi_a(r_1)\,\phi_b(r_2)\, \nabla_1\, \nabla_2\, \phi_c(r_1)\, \phi_d(r_2)\, dr_1\, dr_2
$$
where the bounds of the integrals are $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Is it always true that rewrite this as follows?

$$
=\int\phi_a(r_1)\,\nabla_1\, \phi_c(r_1)\,dr_1\, \int\phi_b(r_2)\,\nabla_2\, \phi_d(r_2)\,dr_2
$$

Comment: I would say yes. If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are independent variables

Comment: @Yuriy S       $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the coordinates vectors of a particle.